# How to round of decimal numbers and get exact sum if added?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to get exact sum of rounded numbers

```
1) Math.round( ( 100/3 + Number.EPSILON ) * 100 ) / 100  // 3.33

2) Math.round( ( 100/3 + Number.EPSILON ) * 100 ) / 100 *3 // 99.99
```

how to get 100 as sum if we add all the rounded numbers ?

Comment: You can't. Rounding drops or alters digits and there is no magical store that secretly keeps the original. If you need the original, then store the original.

Comment: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633)

Comment: Some numbers just can't be represented in the binary floating point format used by JavaScript (and most other languages). Although thirds are representable neither in base 10 nor base 2 floating point, even the decimal value 0.1 cannot be precisely represented by base 2 (IEEE) floating point representation. For example, let's add `0.1` to itself 100 times... `[...Array(100)].reduce((a) => a + 0.1, 0)`. What's the result? Not 10. [Get used to it](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Here's a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482867/what-tricks-does-js-employ-to-show-floating-point-numbers) related to this issue that I just asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rounding to display the numbers nicely, then instead of rounding, try using [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) when you are actually rendering the numbers
eg

```js
let one = ( ( 100/3 + Number.EPSILON ) * 100 ) / 100;
let two = ( ( 100/3 + Number.EPSILON ) * 100 ) / 100 *3;
//when you print use toFixed
console.log(one, one.toFixed(2));
console.log(two, two.toFixed(2));
```

This way, you have your true value and a rounded value

Comment: ( ( 99.99+ Number.EPSILON ) * 100 ) / 100; should be 100.00 but not !?

Answer (score 0):

I can see only two solutions for this maths question:

1. Avoid rounding in the first place
2. Round the result