# What tricks does JS employ to show/caclulate floating point numbers

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Yes, I know all about IEEE floating point numbers.

For instance, there is no precise representation of the decimal value `0.1` in binary floating point maths.

This being the case, what tricks are being used to "round" the result of the expression:

```js
console.log(0.1 * 10)
```

to be ***exactly*** `1` (i.e. `(0.1 * 10) === 1` is `true`) when, if I make my own calculations using addition:

```js
console.log([...Array(10)].reduce((a) => a + 0.1, 0))
```

the result is (on my machine) `0.9999999999999999`.

How does Javascript (and, most likely other runtimes) fudge the multiplication to give the (intuitively) correct answer without falling into the same problem I did when doing this manually?

Comment: I think the problem is the same as this https://0.30000000000000004.com/
It's a floating point problem in your case in step 8 you result is 0.7999999 and after that you add 2 more so 0.89999.. and 0.99999999

Comment: @angel.bonev Indeed, this much is known. However, fundamentally, `0.1` isn't stored internally as `0.1`. It's value, when stored, is closer to `0.100000001490116119384765625`, or represented in 32-bit FP as `00111101110011001100110011001101`. My question relates to how JS fiddles with the multiplication of this value to provide clean decimal-like results when the internal representation of this number is off.

Comment: @angel.bonev For instance, how is `(0.1 * 1000) === 100` true when we know that the facts of the comment above are also true? What's the magic that makes this possible?

Comment: Each individual floating-point operation rounds the ideal mathematical result to the nearest representable value. In `.1 * 10`, the nearest representable value is 1. In `.1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1`, the various additions round up and down in assorted ways, accumulating errors so that the final result is not 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
  1 23456789012345678901234              bit #
  1.10011001100110011001101 * 0.0001     decimal 0.1
x                      1010              decimal 10
---------------------------
         
   1111 1111111111111111111              carries                      
   0011.0011001100110011001101 * 0.0001  1.10011001100110011001101 * binary 10
+  1100.11001100110011001101   * 0.0001  1.10011001100110011001101 * binary 1000
------------------------------
  10000.0000000000000000000001 * 0.0001  = 1 *trailing 1 dropped per LGRS
  12345 6789012345678901234
                          LGRS           LSb Guard Round Sticky
                          0001           ==>round down
```

BTW, 0.999999... == 1  ("proof of this is in Knuth's "Art of Computer Programming" book).  BUT, you are correct, adding the 10 numbers gives a different result, and it is not 1.000..., 0.999..., nor 0.9999999999999999 (all non-whole number floats have 5 as the last non-zero digit to the right of the decimal point), it is:

```
>>> print("%100.100f\n") % (0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1)
0.9999999999999998889776975374843459576368331909179687500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It was suggested I explain the above sum, which is a good suggestion.
I suspect the "proof" is buried in "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#932)--a "must read".  So, I will leave the laborious manual verification as an exercise to the asker.  To help, here is the truth table for LGRS:

```
"first" bit
v
v
v     "last" bit (once set to 1, it NEVER shifts out to 0)
v     v
v     v
L G R S  Round (G, R, and S bits are not in final result)
0 0 0 0  down (means leave L bit as is)
0 0 0 1  down
0 0 1 0  down
0 0 1 1  down
0 1 0 0  down
0 1 0 1  up (means add 1 to L bit)
0 1 1 0  up
0 1 1 1  up
1 0 0 0  down
1 0 0 1  down
1 0 1 0  down
1 0 1 1  down
1 1 0 0  up
1 1 0 1  up
1 1 1 0  up
1 1 1 1  up
```

(not a "proof") Since while adding S==0, the above shows that there are 5 downs vs 3 ups.  Also, since the 1s density is about 50%, the expected results will likely traverse the whole of this 1/2 of the truth table.  So, a loss of magnitude makes sense.  When there is a sticky bit involved the odds even out, or may be stacked the other way.

Comment: This is actually a good answer. Just need to explain a bit more. Also if possible mention why this is different from simply adding the number ten times