# Why do I get different numbers by addition and multiplication?

Tags: javascript, math, multiplication, addition

As far as I know, `2 + 2 + 2` is the same thing as `2 * 3`. The result of both is `6`. Why it's not like that in JS?

```js
let result = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   result += 0.2; //addition
};
console.log(result);

console.log(0.2 * 50); //multiplication
```

Is there some difference in execution between addition and multiplication in JS? What the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: same goes for `0.3 + 0.6` you'd expect `0.9` but get `0.89999999`. Most of the time you'll end up using `floor()` or `ceil()`

Comment: @Ahsan Khan I know that floating numbers are horrible in math operations. But as I see, it extends only to addition. Why it doesn't extend to multiplication too?

Comment: Relevant: [What tricks does JS employ to show/caclulate floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68482867)

Comment: @Ivan it does extend to multiplication too, it depends on the numbers, for ex `0.2 * 3` gives `0.6000000000000001`.